# Problem with matrix operation in openCV

Tags: opencv

I have a problem in my program in openCV when I'm trying to do matrix operations.
for example, if I have 2 matrices and I wanna use the function cvMatMul(&Ma, &Mb, &Mc); let say I wanna multiply Matrix Ma by another matrix Mb when I compile I get no error but when I'm starting operating the program I get this error:

OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /home/mario/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 641
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'

what():  /home/mario/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:641: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat

Can you suggest any solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: **Thank you guys, no need to answer because I have solved the problem. In case that anyone wants to know how it has been solved then just write a comment and I will do that. Thank you**

Comment: Could you tell me how did you resolve ???

Thank you

Comment: I've answered you, and I hope my answer will be satisfied, text me if you didn't get it

Answer (score 4):

@Ricardo:

The problem with me was in creating the matrix so you should create the matrix like this

CvMat* name_of_matrix = cvCreateMat(M,N,CV_32FC1);

and then you don't need to put pointers to the matrices when you do multiply it. 
So for example like this

```
cvMatMul(first_mat, second_mat, output_mat);
```

Comment: Dude I was actually stuck with this error : M0.type() == CV_32F || M0.type() == CV_64F) && M0.rows == 3 && M0.cols == 3 in function CvWarpPerspective(). But changing the value of matrix to Cv_32FC1 instead of CV_8UC1 solved it ! Thanks :)